# Has no method 'addArrayObserver' during {{#linkTo}} click

Tags: ember.js

Hey not sure if anyone can help me, but I have been struggling with this error for a long time:

`"Uncaught TypeError: Object <App.AssetType:ember408:2> has no method 'addArrayObserver'"`

Here is the template with the `{{#linkTo}}`'s that produce this error when clicked

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <h2>{{title}} - Assets</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="three columns">
    <ul>
      {{#each assetTypes}}
      {{#linkTo 'product.filter' this}}{{title}}{{/linkTo}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="nine columns">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</div>
```

and the Application code

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create
  rootElement: '.solution_products_documents'

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.Product.find()
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  sortProperties: ['title']

App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    App.Product.find params.product_id
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set 'documents', model.get 'document_ids'

App.ProductController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  assetTypes: (->
    docs = @get('documents')
    docs.getEach 'asset_type_id'
  ).property('documents')

App.ProductFilterRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    type = App.AssetType.find params.asset_type_id
    product = this.modelFor 'product'
    docs = product.get 'document_ids'
    model = docs.filterProperty 'asset_type_id', type
App.ProductFilterController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()

App.Router.map ->
  @route 'index', { path: '/' }
  @resource 'product', { path: '/products/:product_id' }, ->
    @route 'filter', { path: '/filter-by/:asset_type_id' }

##
# MODELS / EMBER-DATA
##

serializer = DS.JSONSerializer.create()

serializer.configure 'App.Document',
  sideloadAs: 'documents'

serializer.configure 'App.AssetType',
  sideloadAs: 'asset_types'

serializer.configure 'App.Product',
  sideloadAs: 'products'

App.RestAdaptor = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
  serializer: serializer
  namespace: URL.slice 1
DS.Store.extend(
  adapter: App.RestAdaptor
  revision: 11
).create()

App.Product = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  document_ids: DS.hasMany 'App.Document'

App.Document = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  product_id: DS.belongsTo 'App.Product'
  asset_type_id: DS.belongsTo 'App.AssetType'

App.AssetType = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  document_ids: DS.hasMany 'App.Document'

######### /> END MODELS #################
```

Everything works as planned if I put the URL `#/products/4/filter-by/2` into the address bar. It's only when I click the `{{#linkTo}}`'s that I get this error and the content is not displayed. The error is thrown before it get's to the `App.ProductFilterRoute` because the `debugger` statement in the route is not executed, but it is on page refresh.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated, as I don't really know where to look.

**UPDATE:**

If I do not use the `{{#linkTo}}` helper and instead manually construct the url

`<a href="#/products/{{unbound controller.content.id}}/filter-by/{{unbound this.id}}">{{title}}</a>`

everything works fine. What is different between the linkTo and manual href?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error basically says that Ember expects an Array, when you navigate to the ProductFilterRoute.

**Why does Ember expect an Array here?**

1. The **Controller** for your Route (ProductFilterController) **is of type ArrayController**.
2. I am not very familiar with coffeescript, but your **model hook** seems to return an array too. **Important Notice: The model hook is just executed when entering your App via Url.** (This is why your manual navigation by Url and the href both work. Cite from [EmberDoc](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model): "A hook you can implement to convert the URL into the model for this route.")

**Why is the error thrown?**
So your route revolves around an array. You are passing just a plain object. So the golden rule is: **Pass the same data structure (an array in this case) to your {{linkTo}} helper, which is returned by your model hook implementation.**

**A possible solution:**

1. Use an action instead of {{linkTo}}
2. Implement an action in your route that finds all document with the given asset_type and pass it to your route.

Modifiations to template:

```
<a {{action 'filterProductByAsset' this}}> {{title}} </a>
```

Extensions to ProductFilterRoute:

```
events:{
    filterProductByAsset : function(assetTypeId){
        type = App.AssetType.find(asset_type_id);
        product = this.modelFor('product');
        docs = product.get('document_ids');
        models = docs.filterProperty('asset_type_id', type);
        this.transitionTo("product.filter", models)
    }
}
```

Comment: As you see the "filterProductByAsset" action is very similar to your model hook implementation. You should likely extract the logic into an own method and call this new method both from model hook and the filterProductByAsset action.

Comment: Yea this solution worked perfectly, I just had to modify it slightly because `this` is actually the `App.AssetType` model. Now the `/:asset_type_id` is undefined because we are passing it an array of models as a param. This was insanely educational and I really appreciate your breakdown of the different parts.

Comment: I am glad you liked it. :-)

Comment: @Lsdafjklsd how did you go around the problem with the /:asset_type_id now being an array?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
assetTypes: (->
  docs = @get('documents')
  docs.getEach 'asset_type_id'
).property('documents')
```

this looks like it will produce an array like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

When really you need an array of objects that respond to id, e.g.

```
object1 = Em.Object.create id: 1
object2 = Em.Object.create id: 2
[object1, object2] #etc
```

If you want to change this behaviour, you will need to look into the serialize hook of the route you are linking *to*, in this case `product.filter`

With regard to `{{linkTo}}` vs. manually created links, the linkTo helper is js enabled, you should always use it instead of a manual link. This becomes more of a real problem when using the HistoryLocation / pushState support as it forces a full page reload.

There is another problem here: you can't observe documents like this. You must use something like `property('documents.@each')`

Comment: The `assetTypes` function does return an array of ember `AssetType` models. I originally had `property('documents.@each.asset_type_id') but was unclear how far I actually needed to go into documents for what I was trying to do. And you are right abou the javascript generated links.